# einen Deal abschließen vs. schließen

Tags: synonym

AFAIK both expressions below mean "to close a deal":

- einen Deal schließen
- einen Deal abschließen

Is there any difference *in meaning* between them?

I have found both in the [DW newscast](https://www.dw.com/de/13082020-langsam-gesprochene-nachrichten/a-54548860) (the synonym "Geschäft" is used instead of "Deal" with abschließen, probably to avoid repetition):

> Ungarn **schließt Mega-Rüstungsdeal** mit USA
>
> Ungarn will von den USA Raketensysteme für eine Milliarde US-Dollar kaufen. Eine entsprechende Absichtserklärung unterzeichneten der ungarische Verteidigungsminister Tibor Benkö und der US-Botschafter in Budapest, David Cornstein. Mit den radargelenkten Raketen vom Typ AMRAAM des US-Herstellers Raytheon will Ungarn veraltete Systeme ersetzen, die noch aus kommunistischer Zeit stammen. Es ist **das größte Rüstungsgeschäft**, das Ungarn jemals mit den USA **abgeschlossen hat**.

Comment: DW most likely omitted the final "ab" in the heading. News sites these days cannot be trusted to produce correct German anymore. Moreover it's more common "einen Deal zu **machen**".

Answer (score 1):

- schließen
  means, that you close something that was open before. You use it to close blooks, doors, windows, bottles etc.
- abschließen
  can mean to lock something (lock the door), but it also can mean to finish an action

  > Erich hat seine Ausbildung abgeschlossen.
  > Erich has completed his training.

  or it can mean to sign a contract

  > Sonja hat einen Vertrag mit der Versicherung abgeschlossen.
  > Sonja has signed a contract with the insurance company.

  To close a deal falls in the same category as to close (or sign) a contract. So, when you close a deal, you normally do not say "schließen" but "abschließen".

But in German there is also the phrase

> einen Pakt schließen
> *Faust schloss einen Pakt mit Mephistopheles.*
> *Faust made a pact with Mephistopheles.*

Although a pact is a form of a contract, you do not use use the verb *abschließen* when you make a pact. You use *schließen* in this case.

But when you use the noun *Deal* in German, you don't use it together with the verb *schließen* or *abschließen* very often. These are more frequent examples:

> Eva bot Sandra einen Deal an.
> Eva offered Sandra a deal.
>
> Hannes und Markus einigten sich auf einen Deal.
> Hannes and Markus agreed on a deal.
>
> Es war alles vorbereitet, um den Deal für beide Seiten perfekt zu machen.
> Everything was prepared to clinch the perfect deal for both sides.
>
> Barbara besiegelte kurz darauf den Deal mit Michael.
> Barbara sealed the deal shortly after with Michael.